# Accessibility action call back

Tags: ios, ios8, accessibility

while double tap this method is not getting called in iOS.8.x, while its working 
perfect in iOS 9 and iOS 10.

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityActivate

{

    if (self.isEditing) {
        [self.ownerTextDetail messagePicked:self];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Please suggest any solution for iOS 8.x.

Comment: This method is available from "iOS (7.0 and later), tvOS (7.0 and later)" so there is absolutely no need to find alternative for it in iOS 8

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Yes, some reason its not working for iOS 8.